# Switching to a different controller based upon a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Right now, I have a home controller with a function that authenticates the user.  I have it so that if a regular user logs in, the main menu in this controller is returned.  However, I want to make it so that if the user that logs in is an Admin, a whole different view is used.  Therefore, I want to make it use a different controller based upon this condition.  If anyone could help, that would be awesome.  This is a snippet of what I'm looking at now.

```
if (username == "user" && password == "test")
{
    ViewBag.name = (string)username;
    return View("Main", new { name = username });
}
else if (username == "Admin" && password == "test")
{
    ViewBag.name = (string)username;
    //return AdminController main menu view here?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a RedirectToAction:

```
return RedirectToAction("Main", "Admin", new { name = username });
```

Comment: I guess my only question is, why would the action name be set as Main?  I'm new to asp.net so I'm not sure what that is and all.

Comment: You can call it anything you like :)  I just used "Main" as that was your example.

Comment: Ahhhhh, I see.  The action name will just be tacked on so it will appear as Admin/Main and then I'll have to add a Main action result to my Admin Controller so that I can get the Main view I want.  Thank you!

Comment: You got it, that's it :)

Comment: Note that this creates another go around with the client. If there is timing concern you can instead just return a different view by specifying a full path to the view.